# How to pipe openai stream into http response?

Tags: node.js, stream, openai-api

I am creating a server to access openai API:

```
const chat = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [{ role: "user", content: "Say this is a test" }],
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    stream: true,
});
```

How can I pipe the stream into HTTP response?

Comment: What's your goal? What do you mean by saying *stream into HTTP response*? Please tag me when you answer so that I'll see when you do so.

Comment: @RokBenko I am using OpenAI API to provide own chat service. My server consumes the openai API that streaming messages. I need to pipe the openai response stream to the requests that access to my website.